# Localizar un número y multiplicarlo

Tags: r, regex

Quiero localizar una serie de números en una cadena y multiplicarlos por mil

Por ejemplo

```
datos<-data.frame(
  col1=c("rojo 1.3r verde","morado1 345 tortilla","verde 3.4 ","amarillo 4.5t","verde","rojo3"),
  col2=c(NA,3450,NA,NA,2000,3000)
)
```

```
                  col1 col2
1      rojo 1.3r verde   NA
2 morado1 345 tortilla 3450
3           verde 3.4    NA
4        amarillo 4.5t   NA
5                verde 2000
6                rojo3 3000
```

Quiero localizar todo lo que sea digito.digito (no importa que tenga una letra detrás), multiplicarlo por 1000 y añadirlo a col2

El resultado a obtener sería

```
                 col1 col2
1      rojo 1.3r verde   1300   (1.3*1000)
2 morado1 345 tortilla   3450
3           verde 3.4    3400   (3.4*1000)
4        amarillo 4.5t   4500   (4.5*1000)
5                verde   2000
6                rojo3   3000
```

He probado con

```
datos$col2[grepl("(\\d\\.)(\\d)", datos$col1)  & is.na(datos$col2) ]<- "\\1\\2*1000"
```

Obteniendo

```
                  col1        col2
1      rojo 1.3r verde \\1\\2*1000
2 morado1 345 tortilla        3450
3           verde 3.4  \\1\\2*1000
4        amarillo 4.5t \\1\\2*1000
5                verde        2000
6                rojo3        3000
```

También he probado con

```
datos$col2[grepl("(\\d\\.)(\\d)", datos$col1)  & is.na(datos$col2) ]<- gsub(NA, "\\1\\2*1000",datos$col2)

``
sin resultado.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces esto:

```
datos$col2[grepl("(\\d\\.)(\\d)", datos$col1)  & is.na(datos$col2) ]<- "\\1\\2*1000"
```

simplemente estás asignando la cadena `\1\\2*1000` a ciertas filas, creo que me hago una idea de lo que buscas, pero ciertamente así no funciona.

Una aproximación a este problema sería:

- obtener únicamente las cadenas que coinciden con el patrón numérico buscado
- convertirlas a un  número y multiplicarlas por 1000
- reemplazar solo las filas en las que aparece el patrón

Algo así

```
patron <- "\\d+[.]\\d+"
numeros <- as.numeric(regmatches(datos$col1, regexpr(patron, datos$col1))) * 1000 
datos$col2[grepl(patron, datos$col1)] <- numeros
```